# OmniStudioDataRaptor: Id of type reference has invalid value

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity, omniscript

Through a Dataraptor Load, I am trying to create a Person Account then use its `PersonContactId` field on upserting an AccountRelationship record. However, I am getting this error below.

```json
["AccountContactRelation ContactId of type reference has invalid value: DRResultKey:[dataSet=MatchingDataSet:[dataValues=(MatchingDataValue:[compare=uniqueId=, field=uniqueId, fieldType=null, operator==, value=0RootNode|1:1]), fieldSet={uniqueId}, hasComparison=false, isDirty=false, matchingKeyReadable=uniqueId=0RootNode|1:1, matchingKeyString=[{\"value\":\"0RootNode|1:1\",\"operator\":\"=\",\"field\":\"uniqueId\",\"compare\":\"uniqueId=\"}], sObjectType=null], hasNestedLookup=false, matchingKeyReadable=null, matchingKeyString=null, objectType=Account, selectField=PersonContactId]"]
```

This is the Objects tab of the DataRaptor.
[image: DataRaptor Load Objects]

I've already tried importing it again from the source org. I've also tried deleting the link and adding it again.

This works in 2 other environments but not in this sandbox. Has anyone encountered this issue before, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Person Contact Id is a Contact Id, you are trying to assign that to Account.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your setup and did not receive any errors. The error might be related to what information you are mapping to the relevant fields.

Here is my DR Load:

[image]

I also mapped the required values to the `Account` Object and `Account Contact Relation` Object:

```json
{
  "Account": {
    "LastName": "Van Niekerk"
  },
  "AccountContactRelation": {
    "AccountId": "0013z000035yYnMAAU"
  }
}
```

The `AccountContactRelation:AccountId` above is an `Id` of a Business Account record.

A Person Account record was created together with an Account Contact Relation record that associated the Person Account record with the Business Account record:

[image]

Hope this is useful...

Good luck!